# construct a string with the index the composition of an integer array

Tags: c#, string, indexing

i've code for indexes string. What should I add to the code so that the results of the string become.

> if string "hello" to "loleh"

this the code :

```
public void IndexesString() 
{ 
    string karakter = "hello";
    int [] IP = {4,5,3,2,1};
    string Result;
    txtResult.Text = Result; // Result = "loleh"
}
```

Comment: Are you always expecting "hello" to turn into "loleh", or does it need to be random or?

Comment: How did you come from the string "hello" to "loleh" given those indices? If you can describe the steps you took you can probably code it too.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg the indices are given in the `IP` array with a +1 offset.

Comment: @Max I just illustrate, if a string is compiled using an existing index on the variable `IP`

Comment: @Dirk Yes, I get what I mean, look at the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach loop and `StringBuilder` (especially for long strings)

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var i in IP)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(karakter[i-1]);
}

Result = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: `ToString()` call is superfluous here.

Comment: @Dennis yeah, thanks :) I've copied it from previous version where I was using `+=` at string

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "hello";

string result = new string(new[] { str[3], str[4], str[2], str[1], str[0], });
```

More generally, substitute the indices `3`, `4` etc. with `ip[n]` or similar. Can be done in loop of course.

Or what about this:

```
string str = "hello";

int[] ip = { 3, 4, 2, 1, 0, };

var result = new string(Array.ConvertAll(ip, idx => str[idx]));
```

The old `ConvertAll` method of .NET 2 is similar to Linq's `Select` method, but with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Possible *Linq* solution

```
  string karakter = "hello";
  int[] IP = { 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 };

  String result = new String(IP.Select(i => karakter[i - 1]).ToArray());
```

Comment: This is the same as the last part of my answer, however with `Array.ConvertAll` it is known from the outset that we will need a list/array of a specific length, while Linq's `ToArray` cannot know that. However, if one prefers to always stick to the Linq methods (for clarity of the code), your code is really fine.